# Mileage Calculator Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to calculate miles driven for two different companies. I want to make a cell that will add up only data from Company A, and a cell that will add up data from only Company B.

EX:

```
COMPANY       DAYS MILAGE TOTAL        COMPANY A TOTAL     COMPANY B TOTAL    
COMPANY A      10                            20               40

COMPANY B      20

COMPANY A      10

COMPANY B      20
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: I think this question is essentially asking the same thing: [Sum of all cells in Google Spreadsheet where matching row fits a value](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18277)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
=QUERY(A2:B,"SELECT SUM(B) WHERE B IS NOT NULL PIVOT A")
```

or

```
=SUMIF($A2:A,"=" & C2,$B2:B)    // copy this into the adjacent cell
```

or

```
=SUM(FILTER($B2:B,$A2:A=C2))    // copy this into the adjacent cell
```

See example file I created: [Milage per Company](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdHZCdzJ0c3lhUnlDUXBPcjR0V3l6a3c&usp=sharing)

Remark

- The first solution is the shortest, because it covers two answers in 
  the same query. It automatically "grows", when you start adding
  different companies. If you add something in column B, without
  adding something in column A, the table will get messed up. Add a
  company in column A again will return the table to normal.
- The second is the most straightforward of them all.
- The third solution allows for some additional tweaking afterwards